# Postfix Relay access denied after upgrading from 2.11 to 3.4

Tags: postfix

The version 2.11.3 of the Postfix have worked flawlessly for the past couple of years.
After I upgraded it to the version 3.4.14, the server is not able to send emails to external anymore.

In the `mail.err` file, I have found the following line:

```
postfix/smtpd[1043]: fatal: in parameter smtpd_relay_restrictions or smtpd_recipient_restrictions, specify at least one working instance of: reject_unauth_destination, defer_unauth_destination, reject, defer, defer_if_permit or check_relay_domains
```

After that I have configured the both parameters in the `master.cf` to the

```
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=reject_unauth_destination
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=reject_unauth_destination
```

In the Postfix version 2.11, that both parameters were commented out.

After that configuration the message in the `mail.err` was gone but I found another error in `mail.log` file

```
Jun  3 08:01:22 smtp-out postfix/smtpd[19915]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 554 5.7.1 <info@info.com>: Relay access denied; from=<john.smith@test.com> to=<info@info.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<[127.0.0.1]>
```

Since I am using the `sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport_sender` what would be the correct configuration of those two parameters (in case if that is the problem)?

Here is my `main.cf` file:

```
inet_protocols = ipv4
smtpd_banner = Company ESMTP NO UCE/UBE
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
myhostname = smtp-out.company.com
mydomain = company.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = smtp-out.local, localhost.dmz.local.dmz.local, localhost, $mydomain, localhost.$mydomain

relayhost = [mail.external-relayserver.com]

relay_domains =
mynetworks = 192.168.10.0/24, 192.168.15.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8, [::1]/128
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/regexp/header_checks
message_size_limit = 47185920
recipient_delimiter = +

transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport

undisclosed_recipients_header=
local_recipient_maps =
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_loglevel=1

# relay transport
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport_sender
smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous

default_destination_concurrency_limit = 2
default_destination_rate_delay = 1s
```

`master.cf` file:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=reject_unauth_destination
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=reject_unauth_destination

pickup    unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache

maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}

uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)

ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify who is allowed to relay through your postfix server **before** the `reject_unauth_destination`.

e.g. to allow your own networks to relay through your server:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
```

or if you're using sasl_authentication:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated,
                           reject_unauth_destination
```

Remember that these rules are specified in the order listed...so the above allows clients on your networks to relay mail without having to authenticate.  Clients from outside your network have to authenticate themselves.  Relay attempts from everyone else are rejected.

---

BTW, for a simple postfix config like yours it is better to put these options in the `main.cf` file, not `master.cf`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this config, and I will let you know.

Comment: Works as expected. You're a lifesaver!